# jQuery Counter add number to class

Tags: jquery

I'm have a for loop on jQuery and I want my counter to add a class each time with the number of the array it's coming from. But if I write:`.addClass("delay"+counter++)` that obviously won't work. Would there be another way of going about this.

For example this is what I have so far

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var counter = 1;
                $.getJSON('http://www.passionla.com/app/blog-data.php', function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('.blog').append("<div class='post animated slideInRight "+ counter++ +"' style=\"background:url('"+value.header+"') no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%\"><div class='color'><div class='wrapper'><h1>"+value.title+"</h1></div></div></div>");
                    });
                }); 
            });
```

Comment: It wouldn't work but regardless `.addClass` typo*

Comment: Please add more code

Comment: Make a codepen/jsfiddle of what you have tried at least

Comment: what do you mean by won't work....

Comment: try `.addClass("delay"+ ( counter++ ) ) `

Comment: @ArunPJohny it won't work because I have to put "+ counter++ +";

Comment: @TamilSelvan that works, but its putting delay1 - delay14 on everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably easier to increase the counter as a variable and then attach the variable to the class:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1xv6zz0/2/)

```
$('div').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var newClass = "delay" + i++;
    $this.addClass(newClass);
});
```

But you would use the `.each()` function on your returned data instead of `div`.